# Angular 2 - routing with path as parameter and BrowserSync

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, browser-sync

I've this on my code...

```
@RouteConfig([
{path: "/me", name: "Me", component: MeComponent, useAsDefault: true},
{path: "/me/edit", name: "EditProfile", component: EditProfileComponent},
{path: "/people/:group", name: "People", component: PeopleComponent}
])
```

but in order to make something like /people/school I need to set the routes on the browserSync. My first attempt was a wildcard, like this:

```
browserSync.init({
   server: {
        baseDir: "./",
        routes: {
            "/me": "index.html",
            "/me/edit" : "index.html",
            "/people/*" : "index.html"
        }
    }
```

It's not working. Any suggestion about how to configure browserSync to work with dynamic generated url paths ?

ty !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could configure your app to use [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/HashLocationStrategy-class.html).

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy })
]);
```

Or configure Browser Sync [rewriteRules](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-rewriteRules) to rewrite your Angular 2 route paths to the application root `index.html`.

Comment: OP is trying to handle HTML5 routes under Browsersync. Browsersync rewriteRules are for html _content_, _not_ URL rewrites. OP needs to instead use Browsersync Middleware. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform URL Rewrites, directing requests to your HTML 5 routes back to your `index.html` page.

```js
var bsConfig = {
    "open": baseUrl,
    "server": { 
        //... 
    },
    middleware: function(req,res,next) {

        /*
            Re-write URL for each of our Angular routes, mapping them back to index.html (for single-page app, HTML5 routing)
        */
        switch (req.url) {
            //for all angular routes, re-rewrite to /index.html
            case baseUrl + '/customers' : 
            case baseUrl + '/products' : 
            case baseUrl + '/transactions' : 
            
            req.url = '/index.html';
            
            default : {
                //for all other requests (e.g.: to static content such as .css files) don't make any URL re-writing.
                break;
            }
            
        }

        return next();
    }
};


browserSync.init(bsConfig);
```

Credit to: 
https://vinaygopinath.me/blog/tech/url-redirection-with-browsersync/